# How nodetool rebuild works

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have cluster of 4 cassandra nodes in aws singapore region (4 cores,32 GB RAM). I need to migrate it to mumbai region so i created a new cluster of 3 nodes in mumbai region and named it as a different datacenter and changed the clients accordingly. I run nodetool rebuild to replicate the data from old datacenter to new datacenter. Data on disk is showing around 150GB but when i run nodetool status is showing only 26 GB. Cassandra version 3.9. The nodetool rebuild is still running.

Answer (score 0):

150GB can be backups/snapshots/stale data. Check the sub directories of data.

When you created new cluster, did you copied data from the old one/used image of old server?

Nodetool rebuild should copy all the data.

Comment: No the new machines dont have any snapshots and i didnt copies anything from old servers

Comment: Did your rebuild stopped in the middle? Do your cluster are on heavy load? Also try to compare files in data directories, for any large table between old dc and new dc.

Comment: The data updated by nodetool automatically thanks for the help